# Wireless not working on Dell Latitude E6400 with Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: networking, wireless

I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.04.2 to a new hard drive in a Dell Latitude E6400. Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to get the wireless working. I know the hardware works because my other hard drive is Windows and everything works great there. I am trying to learn Ubuntu and not really sure where to go. I opened a terminal and ran `lspci` and the wireless card is a Broadcom BCM4312. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the drivers installed? Check the additional drivers tab in software properties (`software-properties-gtk`).

Answer (score 6):

If you **have** internet access through wired ethernet, run these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

---

If you **don't have** internet access, then download the following on another computer and copy it to your E6400 in the home folder (/home/your_username/):

1. b43-fwcutter [32-bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/b43-fwcutter_018-2_i386.deb) package or [64-bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/b43-fwcutter_018-2_amd64.deb) package depending on your OS.
2. b43-firmware [broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2](http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2).

Then execute the following commands in the terminal:

```
$ cd ~
$ sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter*
$ tar xfvj broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
$ sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
```

---

Once you are done, don't forget to **restart** your computer.

---

Reference: [Ubuntu Broadcom WifiDocs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)

Comment: the apt package still works in 2023

Answer (score 0):

If you see "wifi not ready" just restart the network-manager with:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```